# Searchalgorithm in Modelica/Dymola

Tags: algorithm, modelica, dymola

I'm currently trying to create a Modelica-Code, that searchs through an Array full of strings, compares them to strings in a different Array and safes the location where it found it and the location of the initial Matrix.

My Code as an example can be seen here:

```
parameter String Matrix[3,3]={{"Pumpe1","Widerstand1","Ventil1"},{"Zweig","Widerstand2","Ventil2"},{"Druckrand","Widerstand3","Ventil3"}};
 
 parameter String Ueberschrift[1,5]={{"Ventil1","Pumpe1","Druckrand","Ventil3","Ventil2"}};
 Integer Stringvergleich;
 Integer Ortsvektor[9,3];
 Integer Laufvariable;
algorithm 
  Laufvariable:=0;
  
  for i in 1:3 loop 
    for l in 1:3 loop 
      Laufvariable:=Laufvariable + 1;
      for m in 1:5 loop 
        Stringvergleich:=Modelica.Utilities.Strings.find(Ueberschrift[1,m],Matrix[i,l]);
        if not Stringvergleich==0 then
          Ortsvektor[1,Laufvariable]:=i;
          Ortsvektor[2,Laufvariable]:=l;
          Ortsvektor[3,Laufvariable]:=m;
        end if;
      end for;
    end for;
  end for;
```

Unfortunately this code seems to be wrong, but I can't figure out what the Problem is. Dymola sends the following Error message:
Index out of bounds
Failed condition: (j>=1)&&(j<=dim)
Error: Integrator failed to start model.

Comment: If you swap the dimensions of `Ortsvektor` the code runs. However, I'm not sure if you get the intended results

Comment: @ReneJustNielsen I feel kinda stupid for not realising that I messed up my Array configuration. Thank you for pointing it out and I also want to thank you for the "TestPumpCurve"-Script that you uploaded a couple of years ago!